# How to convert the now() to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I was building my own php app, I am a php beginner so when i want to get the time that a user does a particular action, I used the NOW() function to get it, but my questions is how can i convert the value which I got from the mysql NOW() function to timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better yet, do it all in MySQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() );
```

Comment: thank you for answers, all methods worked prefectly, at least now i have different choices

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function to convert a date string to a timestamp it is called: `strtotime()`.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP( NOW() )
```

This should get you the timestamp ;)

OR, in PHP:

```
$now = strtotime($dbdata->currentDate);
```